# Ceasing a method from executing to move onto the next method

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Was a little confused about this one so I thought I'd post. Sorry if my title is not clear, very new to java and wasn't sure how to explain it. Anyway Here are my sets of code so far ( the problem bits i guess)

```
int currentImageIndex = 0; // Assuming [0] is your first image.
int[] nextImageList = { 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0, 1 };

public void nekoRun() {
    moveIn();
    scratch();
    moveOut();

private void moveIn() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getWidth()/2; i+=10) {
        xPos = i;
        // swap images
        if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
            currentImage = nekoPics[1];
        else 
            currentImage = nekoPics[0];
        repaint();
        pause(150);

private void scratch() {
    for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth();) {
        xPos = i;

        // Swap images.
        currentImageIndex = nextImageList[currentImageIndex];
        currentImage = nekoPics[currentImageIndex];



            repaint();
            pause(150);
        }
}

private void moveOut() {
    for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth(); i+=10) {
        xPos = i;
        // swap images
        if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
            currentImage = nekoPics[1];

        else 
            currentImage = nekoPics[0];
        repaint();
        pause(150);
    }   
}
```

So basically what happens( this is not all of the code just the "juicy parts", a cat will run across the screen and then sit and its supposed to scratch twice, I got some help with the array since I was just using a whole heap of else if statements, and I knew that was superfluous. The cat will run to the centre, it will scratch, and keep scratching, in a loop, for obvious reasons, i'm just confused at how I can get it to move onto the moveOut method rather than keep looping the scratch. Sorry if this is a bit unclear, i am very new at this, so bear with me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as an aside, have you considered renaming your `scratch()` method `scratchTwice()`. It's fairly unimportant here, but I'm sure you can see the value of having method names that reflect *precisely* their functionality in larger and more complicated systems.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is called infinite loop... Instead of

```
private void scratch() {
    for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth();) {
```

This should read

```
private void scratch() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*<how many frames the scratching takes>; i++) {
    // **UPDATE** the xPos=i; shouldn't be here!!!
```

Explanation:

It seems that you have copied the loop definition from the moveIn() function, which seems legit in that case. Something happens, unitl it reaches the middle of the screen. But in the `scratch()` function, the sprite doesn't move, it is not going to reach the endo of the screen ever... So ozu have to repeat the drawing steps two times how many frames the scratching spans. You'll have to put that numnber into the `<how many frames the scratching takes>` placeholder, and it should work.

**EDIT** the `xPos=i`; shouldn't be present in the `scratch()`...

Comment: hmm... this makes the cat reset though, and any idea how to find out how many frames the scratching takes, ideally the cat should be still, scratch twice, then my other function should execute taking him to the end of the screen, whilst running

Comment: @user1667456 Oh, I see another problem. Hang on a second!

Comment: oh i just fixed it, lol, silly error had a xPos = i floating in there for some reason

Comment: @Sim Yep, exactly that was it :)

Answer (score -1):

You are not incrementing i in scratch() put i++ at end of the for statement.

```
for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth(); i++)
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants, as getWidth() is returning the screen width. This would repeat getWidth()/2 times, as the sprite is already at the middle of the screen... And he also doesn't want to move the image dirung the "scratch" phase...